# jQuery click and background sound with on and off switch function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need jQuery click and background sound with an on and off switch.

The following is important:

1. The background sound should start playing infinitely looped when the pages is loaded. But: Everything should be silent at the beginning.
2. If you click the "Sound on" button, the background sound should be audible. Also then, the click sound should be audible.
3. More than one click sound should possibly be audible at one time.
4. If you click then the "Sound off" button, everything should be silent again.

This is what I've coded so far:

```js
$(".sound_control").click(function() {
  $(".on_off").toggle();
});


$(document).ready(function() {

  var background_sound = document.createElement("audio"); // This is the background sound function.
  background_sound.src = "https://www.pacdv.com/sounds/ambience_sounds/airport-gate-1.mp3";
  background_sound.volume = 0.1;
  background_sound.autoPlay = true;
  background_sound.preLoad = true;
  background_sound.controls = true;
  $("*").hover(function() { // The sound should start playing when the website is loaded. I think the hover function is not the best solution. Also, the sound should be looped.
    background_sound.play();
  });

  var click_sound = document.createElement("audio"); // This is the click sound function. It should work for every button with the .click_sound class.
  click_sound.src = "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Stapler-SoundBible.com-374581609.mp3";
  click_sound.volume = 0.1;
  click_sound.autoPlay = false;
  click_sound.preLoad = true;
  click_sound.controls = true;
  $(".click_sound").click(function() {
    click_sound.play();
  });

});
```

```css
.on_off:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="sound_control">Sound <span class="on_off">on</span><span class="on_off">off</span></button>

<button class="click_sound">Button One</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Two</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Three</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Four</button>
```

I would be so happy if someone could help me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** you can  use   `currentTime`  property of HTML5 Audio element  to restart the audio

set it to `0`  then  play() the sound again

**2.** replace the hover event with `background_sound.loop = true;` to play background sound onload

**3.** for the background sound toggling use this inside on/off-button `.click` event

**4.** add variable `SOUND_ON`  & inside buttons click check`if(SOUND_ON){}` then play click sound

```
 if (background_sound.currentTime){
  background_sound.currentTime = 0;
  background_sound.pause();
  }else{
    background_sound.play();  
  }
```

run code below ... hope that help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var SOUND_ON = 1;
  var background_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  background_sound.src = "https://www.pacdv.com/sounds/ambience_sounds/airport-gate-1.mp3";
  background_sound.volume = 0.1;
  background_sound.autoPlay = true;
  background_sound.loop = true;
  background_sound.controls = true;
  background_sound.play();


  var click_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  click_sound.src = "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Stapler-SoundBible.com-374581609.mp3";
  click_sound.volume = 0.1;
  click_sound.autoPlay = false;
  click_sound.preLoad = true;
  click_sound.controls = true;


  $(".click_sound").click(function() {
    if (SOUND_ON) {
      click_sound.currentTime = 0;
      click_sound.play();
    }
  });

  $(".sound_control").click(function() {
    $(".on_off").toggle();
    if (background_sound.currentTime) {
      background_sound.currentTime = 0;
      SOUND_ON = 0;
      background_sound.pause();
    } else {
      SOUND_ON = 1;
      background_sound.play();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.on_off:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="sound_control">Sound <span class="on_off">on</span><span class="on_off">off</span></button>

<button class="click_sound">Button One</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Two</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Three</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Four</button>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much! One thing: The click sound should be also silent at the beginning and if the sound is turned off. How is it possible to code it like that?

Comment: edited the code see #4 point  .......   please  vote &accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Create one boolean variable and change its value to True/False accordingly when a user clicks "Sound on" button. Check its value every time "Sound on" or its changed form of "Sound off" clicked. With that you can play and stop the sound.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Hm. How is it possible to do that?

Comment: Your click sounds work. I assume the problem is this sound is long and after click sound it has muted part: http://soundbible.com/mp3/Stapler-SoundBible.com-374581609.mp3. So even though your coding does work, you may not hear another click sound instantly because previous one still playing. That is why it works after every 2 seconds

Comment: But there must be a way to make it possible to activate two sounds at one time?

Comment: It is. Even in your code you can see that click and that background sound play at the same time. The problem is you try to play the same sound again and again without waiting it ends. You have two options: 1) Stop and play the sound again when any sound button clicked. 2) You may add this sound for every click button independently, it will work but not efficient

Comment: Hmm, okay ... :(